# My Views in Dynamics 365 not appearing

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

When one of our users is creating views with Advanced Find, the views appear in his My Views until he refreshes the page, and disappear after it. I reproduced it on few computers with different browsers and for different entities in CRM. It is working as expected for other users. I already tried to remove and add CRM licenses for this user.
Any ideas?

Comment: One thing I would check is, between user views showing the view & disappearing once refreshed, I will quickly check in xrmtoolbox to see if it’s really created in backend?

Comment: Did this user try it with different browsers? Did he clear his browser's cache completely? What are his privileges on the User Query entity?

Comment: I tried it on different computers with different browsers. Same problem for this specific user. In additional I tried to create new view using my account and shared it with this user. It is not appear as well.

Comment: @ArkadyKarasin have you tested with another security role to that user or same role to you, this will Pin point the privilege missing in role.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I created support request for Microsoft. They ran some script on their side and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We experienced this today, shared personal views & dashboards not shown for a particular user.

Removing roles or unsharing/resharing didn’t solve the issue. In all cases, POA table was showing perfect access levels (used xrmtoolbox - search POA plugin). But Access checker xrmtoolbox plugin reveals no access for those saved views (userquery) & user dashboard (userform).

**The issue is solved after removing/assigning license in O365.**

Another observation: User’s last name changed & asked for AD account modification, our help desk created dupe profile & merged. This could have messed the systemuser entry.